# How do you change the default value on a CCK text field that is part of a field group via hook_form_alter()?

Tags: entities, 6

I'm trying to programmatically set the default value (#default_value) on a textfield added via CCK. This field is in a field group. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_id_form_alter().
 */
function EXAMPLE_form_profile_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  // We need to jump into a CCK field, so say we all.
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'EXAMPLE_form_profile_node_form_after_build';
}

function EXAMPLE_form_profile_node_form_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['group_company_profile']['field_pro_name']['#default_value'][0]['value'] = t('test');

  return $form;
}
```

I've tried various other points in the array and nothing seems to work. Both CCK and my module are weight 0. I must be missing something super obvious...?

**UPDATE**: One mistake was the field name. It should be field_pro_name. Updated above. It's still not working. Interestingly, I can use the after build to change the field title with:

```
$form['group_company_profile']['field_pro_name'][0]['value']['#title'] = 'ttt';
```

However, none of these changes the default value:

```
// In form alter:
$form['group_company_profile']['field_pro_name'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = 'ttt';
$form['group_company_profile']['field_pro_name'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'ttt';

// In after build:
$form['group_company_profile']['field_pro_name'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'ttt';
$form['group_company_profile']['field_pro_name'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = 'ttt';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* be able to do something like this:

```
function EXAMPLE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id=='profile_node_form') {
    $form['group_company_profile']['field_pro_type'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = 'hello world';
  }

  // all other form alters here...

}
```

or

```
function EXAMPLE_form_profile_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $form['group_company_profile']['field_pro_type'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = 'hello world';

}
```

directly from whichever form_alter() style you like.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it did not work. I verified the alter is firing.

Comment: Ok, it worked here so something must be different between systems :(

Comment: I did just notice a cut and paste type in my answer (didn't have a closing ] after 'field_pro_type' that I just fixed :)

Comment: Thanks! Re: typo, I submitted an edit for that. Guess it's not needed. Also, it works for you? Grrr! Thank you very much for trying, will dig deeper. :)

Comment: Yah, none of that array exists in the form_alter, which is (I thought) expected, since it's CCK.

Comment: Well, keep on truckin.  One issue that confuses me is I don't know why you have `users_form....` in any of this as it should just be `profile_node_form` but we all know about `should` with respect to all of this :)

Comment: Oh, man. Paste fail! "users" was part of the module name I forgot to replace with EXAMPLE. Sorry. Also, the "form" is causing I'm using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().

Comment: OH MAN, fail on my part. I didn't actually test your code in the form_alter, I did it in hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() (which was firing). No idea why it works in the form_alter, but it does. Thanks!

Comment: *should* to the rescue once again :)  glad it works!

Comment: PS -- given there is actually a `user_form` I bet that was confusing drupal in your specific alter (and another reason underscores are frowned upon in module names)

Comment: Thanks! But the module name part was "_users" not "user." Had no idea underscores in module names was frowned upon. Good to know!